# Powershell 5 draw a triangle out of asterisks

Tags: powershell

I have to write a program that draws a triangle out of asterisks(*) in Powershell 5.

As far as i was able to figure it out, i have a problem with the "using_system" part...

Here is what i have written by now:

```
using_System;
static int Main(){
for (int i = 0; i -lt 5; i++)
    {
    for (int x = 0; x -lt 5; x++)
    {
    Console.Write(" ");
    }

    for (int j = 5 - i; j -gt 0; j--)
    {
    Console.Write(" ");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k -lt 2 * i + 1; k++)
    {
    Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
clear-host
return 0;
}
```

---

If possible, i would like to include a principle that allows the user to input the wanted height of the triangle(how many lines it should consist of).

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I did that, the reason why i included the original c++, was just so people could see what i was trying to do because i think i explained it poorly.

Comment: I think people reacted negatively to the code translation part even though you had powershell code. Most code translation questions are please translate this for me.. Which never goes well.

Comment: Maybe you should show the output as text.

Comment: Your question is vague, it should rather point to a specific problem you encountered. Furthermore the C++ tag should be removed because your question only concerns powershell now.

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but that's why i posted the question in the first place. i am having trouble translating it, because i am fairly new to powershell. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: @Asu the thing that is causing me problems is the 
"using_System;
 static int Main()"
Part
Even though i checked it online already i don't seem to understand how to propperly initialize the function i think..

Comment: You should edit the question for that and also provide detail on your problem and how you tried to solve it as much you can - I believe that your question was downvoted partly for this reason. Also it seems that the problem you're dealing with is sort of unrelated to the triangle printing and more about how to build a basic program.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to write one probably not efficient but it makes triangles

```
function BuildTriangle([int]$Size){
    $OrignalSize = $Size
    $Count = 0
    while($Size -gt 0){
        $($Size) | %{
        if($Size -eq $OrignalSize){
                "$('*'.PadLeft([math]::Floor(($_))," "))"
            }elseif($Size -gt 1){
                "$('*'.PadLeft([math]::Floor(($_))," "))$(@(1..$Count) | %{" "})*"
            }else{
                "$(@(1..$($Count+1)) | %{"*"})"
            }
        }
        $Count += 1
        $Size -= 1
    }

}

BuildTriangle -Size 5
```

Comment: Thank you. That works great. How would i modify the code to fill the entire triangle with *?
 For example:
     *
    ***
  *****
To display a full pyramid..

Answer (score 1):

here are two ways to do the job. the 1st attempts to follow the C++ code, while the 2nd takes a "build a string" approach ... both output a pyramid that is 5 lines high with a base that is 9 chars wide.

```
for ($i= 0; $i-lt 5; $i++)
    {
    for ($x = 0; $x -lt 5; $x++)
        {
        Write-Host ' ' -NoNewline
        }

    for ($j = 5 - $i; $j -gt 0; $j--)
        {
        Write-Host ' ' -NoNewline
        }

    for ($k = 0; $k -lt 2 * $i+ 1; $k++)
        {
        Write-Host '*' -NoNewline
        }
    Write-Host ''
    }
```

a "more powershell-ish to me" take on it ...

```
$HowTall = 5
$Padding = $HowTall - 1
$AsteriskCount = 1

Clear-Host
''

foreach ($HT_Item in 1..$HowTall)
    {
    $Spaces = ' ' * $Padding
    $Asterisks = '*' * $AsteriskCount

    $Spaces + $Asterisks + $Spaces

    $Padding --
    $AsteriskCount += 2
    }

''
```

output from each is identical ...

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what i needed. I tried a slightly different version of the 1st attempt but i misunderstood the "output" part of it.

Comment: @GabrielRatek - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]